# How to bind DropDownList in Gridview with data NOT from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Half the battle of getting an answer is knowing how to ask the question. I am not certain I am doing a good job of that but this is my best shot.

I'm trying to bind a ddl with data inside a gridview that is NOT coming from the gridview itself. This is within the EditItemTemplate.  The purpose for doing so is to give the user, to start, a selected value and a series of other values from a lookup stored procedure.

I'll mention here that I have done this successfully before but using an ObjectDataSource.  I am trying to avoid that this time and do it entirely from the code behind for now then move it to a data layer later.

Here is what I have so far...

```
<asp:GridView ID="usersGrid" runat="server"                 
        DataKeyNames="userID" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="580" 
        OnRowUpdating="usersGrid_RowUpdating"
        OnRowEditing="usersGrid_RowEditing" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="usersGrid_RowCancelingEdit"                                   OnRowDeleting="usersGrid_RowDeleting" 
        >
```

...

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                <div class="gridName">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" Text='<%#Eval("firstName") %>' runat="server" Width="95" />
                </div>
                <div class="gridName">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" Text='<%#Eval("lastName") %>' runat="server" Width="95" />
                </div>
                <div class="gridEmail">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>' runat="server" Width="245" />
                </div>
                <div class="gridName">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_GetLists" 
                    DataSourceID="GetListData()"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                    DataValueField="listID"
                    DataTextField="listName"
                    SelectedValue='<%#Bind("listID") %>'
                    runat="server"
                    >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```

....

```
Protected Sub usersGrid_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    usersGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindData()

End Sub
```

....

```
Private Sub BindData()
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("MAINT_DIST_GET_USERS", conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ad.Fill(ds)
    GetListData()
    usersGrid.DataSource = ds
    usersGrid.DataBind()

End Sub
```

I'm including last two as well as other approaches I've tried and failed.

...

```
    Protected Sub usersGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddl_GetLists"), DropDownList)

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("MAINT_DIST_GET_LISTS", conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        ad.Fill(ds)

        ddl.DataSource = ds
        ddl.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Public Function BindDropdown() As DataSet
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("MAINT_DIST_GET_LISTS", conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    ad.Fill(ds)

    ddl_GetLists.DataSource = ds
    ddl_GetLists.DataBind()
End Function
```

I'll also ask why, in the final function, why is the control, ddl_GetLists, not recognized as well?  Inside the grid it disappears from the designer but outside of the grid it reappears.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You can use a datasource control, or you can bind the dropdowns in code-behind in the `RowDataBound` event of the GridView.

I noticed a couple of issues in your code too. In your example you're assigning the `DataSourceID` incorrectly. The `DataSourceID` should point to the ID of a datasource control on the page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_GetLists"     
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"    
    AppendDataBoundItems="true"    
    DataValueField="listID"    
    DataTextField="listName"    
    SelectedValue='<%#Bind("listID") %>'    
    runat="server">    
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"                  
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"                  
    SelectCommand="SELECT listID, listName FROM SomeTable">                                             
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If you want to do the binding in code-behind, you can do this through the `RowDataBound` event:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddl_GetLists"), DropDownList)
        If ddl IsNot Nothing Then
            ddl.DataSource = RetrieveDataSource()
            ddl.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've successfully done something similar to this using an ObjectDataSource in the past but I'm trying to do this exclusively from the code behind this time.  Is this possible?

Comment: Regarding the ConnectionStrings property.  The app I've been assigned to append uses a key in appSettings instead of the normal connectionstring attribute from the config file.  Is there a way to call on it from sqldatasource?

Comment: @JohnKinane: I think you can still bind `OnRowDataBound`. I edited my answer to bind the dropdown if the row is in edit mode.

Comment: Yes.  It's purpose is to allow the user to select different options from a lookup sp.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: I am facing the same issue, cant get the values in the dropdownlist which is inside the gridview. And I need the same vb code in c#. help please

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a global list of type that you want and set it as null
if you are using linq then just put that source in the DropDownListObject.DataSource

```
DropDownListObject.DataSource=ObjListSource;
DropDownListObject.DataBind;
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple issues.

```
Protected Sub usersGrid_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    usersGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindData()

End Sub
```

Why are you doing this?  Why would you bind the grid again on an event on your grid thats already been filled?

Comment: The second part of your answer is incorrect. There shouldn't be a problem finding the control using that ID.

Comment: I should note that while using VS 2010 that the ddl control, while in the gridview is "not" visible" to the application but when I take it out of the grid it "is".  I have no explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You fix this:

1. In the code page, you define a GetListData() public function (i think you did).
2. Use DataSource property (if you want to call a function) :

   ```
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_GetLists" 
                                 DataSource='<%# GetListData() %>'
                                 AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                 DataValueField="listID"
                                 DataTextField="listName"
                                 SelectedValue='<%#Bind("listID") %>'
                                 runat="server" >
               </asp:DropDownList>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You can put some linebreaks in your content if you let 2 spaces at the end of line. This makes answer clearer.