# Binding a dictionary (within a list) to a dropdown in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to populate a dropdown from a dictionary that is built up within a list, so for example the list is built up from an Events class (in the example it has been cut down a tad):

```
public class Events
{

    public Events()
    {
        StartDate = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "eventId")]
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "eventName")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "startDate")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

And then the actual data binding:

```
    protected void submitSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {

            IEnumerable<Events> events = EventProvider.FindEvents(eventName.Text);
            eventSearchResults.DataSource = events;
            eventSearchResults.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

In the page I have:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start date">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <p>
               <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" Text="Start month/year" runat="server" /><br />
               <asp:DropdownList ID="ddlStartDate" DataSource='<%# Eval("startDate") %>' runat="server" />
           </p>    
        </ItemTemplate>
```

But both the key and value are being added to the value field in the dropdown.  Where am I going wrong?  Any examples would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152925/how-to-bind-dropdownlist-in-gridview-with-data-not-from-gridview) can help you ? Basically you have to define something like

```
DataValueField="listID" DataTextField="listName" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("listID") %>'
```

Comment: I guess it's just a case of not knowing how to achieve that from a dictionary (I can't really move away from that) within a list.  You'd almost need to write: <asp:DropdownList ID="ddlStartDate" DataValueField='<%# Eval("startDate.Key") DataTextField="startDate.Value" %>' runat="server" /> but of course that wouldn't work.